# What was the reason why 9M-MRO burned more fuel on one engine?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, boeing-777, mh370-incident

MH370 Factual Information reported "Right engine consumes average 1.5T more fuel per/hour compared to left engine" on p.28 (page 47 on page count)

http://mh370.mot.gov.my/download/FactualInformation.pdf

Looking at spotters photos on the web I spotted the following difference:

*Some kind of visible replacement (partial or total) to the left engine was made after Oct 28 '13 and before Jan 22 '14.*

**Before** - Two shades, longer curving, bigger bulge on top engine border before exhaust.

**After** - One shade, steeper curving, smaller bulge on top engine border before exhaust.

Google Drive document with links to 9M-MRO photos (I can't post more than 2 links since not enough reputation still)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tkY6H8zQmOyJj0M2_gd_j81iDr2MeumBoIlrYNtbcus/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't see anything on "Page 28" that says what you say.

Comment: Look at the printed page numbering. Not the page count.

Comment: Page 28, section 1.6.3.7, Table of Deferred Items, Row #3.

Comment: Most of what you see on the outside is not actually attached to the engine, and can be changed independently.

Comment: If you read your post, you will see that it does not contain a question.  I don't understand what you are looking for.  Is it why can one engine burn more fuel than another, or some vague point about engine differences which don't seem to be substantiated in any links you've provided?

Answer (score 10):

Those engines all look the same to me.

1.5T per/hour difference does seem excessive, but probably not unheard of.  It could be just because one engine is newer than the other and has less wear on it.

If you look at APPENDIX 1.6B of that same report it shows that the right engine consumed about 1.5% more fuel during Takeoff and Climb, not 1.5T more, so it may just be a typo.

(APPENDIX 1.6B WF is fuel flow in lbs/hr)

[image]
[image]

Here are some crops of the photos you linked to:

[image]
Jan. 15, 2012

---

[image]
Feb. 16, 2013

---

[image]
Oct. 28,2013

---

[image]
Jan. 22, 2014

---

[image]
Feb. 8, 2014

---

[image]
Feb. 10, 2014

---

[image]

Comment: They look the same to me too. I think the color differences are just the light. I put them in order by date. Hope you don't mind

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think the differences are only due to the lighting and the viewing angles.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I still see the last three photos having same color over all the engine. Also in other 2014 photos same thing. Odd.

Comment: Even if they were different, it is just the outside panels.  It is not proof that the engines were changed.

Comment: @ctatti: I see a two-tone engine paintjob on the last two photos (although I agree, it isn't as visible in them as in the first three), and would probably see one on the third from the last as well were it not washed out by the glare from the sun reflecting off the engine.